# oracle: what is the oracle equivalent data type for COMMENT?

Tags: oracle, text, block, comments

What is the datatype in oracle i should be using to store comment boxes? I was going to use LONG but it only allows one. Or should I just use VARCHAR2 and set it really large?

Comment: `LONG` is much larger than `VARCHAR2`, but deprecated in favour of `CLOB`.

Comment: isnt clob character only? id need to include numbers and special characters too

Comment: the term "character" means more than just alphabetic characters - it includes numeric and special characters as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is the longest comment you want to be able to support?

If your comments are less than 4000 bytes in length, you can use a VARCHAR2(4000).  If your comments are longer than 4000 bytes in length, you can use a CLOB.  A CLOB can store any character data supported by your database character set.

Comment: in my case, there is comma separated string which goes to length beyond 27000 characters, CLOB supported upto that only. Is there any alternate to CLOB or How to increase length of database character set?

Comment: @HardikBhalani - What version of Oracle?  In 12.1 and later, you can configure the database to allow tables to have `varchar2(32000)` columns.  Otherwise, you'd want to use a `clob`.  A database character set does not have a length so I'm not sure what your last question is attempting to ask.  I'm not sure what problem you have with a `CLOB` that leads you to want an alternative.  What problem would an alternative solve?  Of course, storing a comma separated string in a relational database in the first place is highly concerning since it violates basic normalization.

Comment: I am using Oracle 11g, I am not using column having comma separated string as its value. I need to use that string in my pl/sql code block that may have character length above 27000. I tried using CLOB that supports upto 27000 characters only. As of now, I can go with CLOB .

Comment: @HardikBhalani - I don't understand what you mean by a "CLOB that supports up to 27000 characters only".  A CLOB supports, depending on the Oracle version and environment, at least terabytes of data and likely petabytes.  Supporting more than 27,000 characters in a CLOB is no problem.